# Phantomjs / Splinter - Issue with cache

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I have an EC2 ubuntu instance where I have planned a script twice a day. 
The script uses Splinter Python lib with PhantomJs headless browser to test some button and actions on my website.

I have just noticed that my T1.micro instance is slower and slower, until my script is not launching anymore.

Run `du` on my instance and found that Phantomjs takes a lot of memory on my disk.
[image]

Can I remove thoses files? 
How can I prevent this stack of files ?

Can't find anything related on Splinter nor Phantomjs.
Thanks!

Comment: That's quite a lot. Does the script/page store a lot of information in the `localStorage`?

Comment: Is five megabytes a lot of disk space for T1.micro?

Comment: @artjom yes I scrapes many variable / items to acces the correct button but I would expect it to delete it after the script run. does it actually store everything?

Comment: @vaviloff yep it is I think

Comment: It doesn't delete it automatically, so you need to do it yourself. If you don't need the contents, then you can delete the folders.

Comment: @Vaviloff It's 5 gigabytes